# Ember: How to render an element every n elements in a list?

Tags: javascript, list, ember.js, pagination, each

After searching and reading docs, I can't find a straight-forward solution to this problem:

**Rendering a list of items from an ArrayController, I want to insert a position or page indicator every N elements.**

I would appreciate any ideas on the Ember way to do this!

Normally I would assume, that this could be handled in the template, something like...

```
each listitems
    if index % 5 == 0
        insert indicator
```

... but Ember doesn't expose the index and Handlebars templates are supposed to be logic free.

Second approach I can think of is to use the ArrayController and set a property on every nth object in the array, but why should the object need to be aware of this? Setting a property feels like cluttering and a lot of potential for errors.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build your own helper. BTW you can access index using `_view.contentIndex` inside each. So you can write a custom helper which basically inserts required html.

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('indicator', function(index,options){
       var html = '';
       if(index%2) {
          html = '<hr />';
       }
       return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(html);
});
```

And call that by passing index. Here is the working jsbin
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/niguwa/1/edit

Comment: Nice solution, with one caveat though: _view.contentIndex is a private property and might disappear in future Ember.js releases without notice. So I'm still looking for the Ember-way to do this. ;-)